# Hibernate: Find entity from one to many table

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `heroic_quality`
(
    `id`   INT          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(515) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `hero`
(
    `id`         INT            NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`       VARCHAR(515)   NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `quality_id` INT            DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY  (`quality_id`) REFERENCES heroic_quality (id),
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

And the objects in hibernate are

```
@Table(name = "heroic_quality")
@Entity(name = "heroic_quality")
public class HeroicQuality
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Hero> heroes;

    //ommited getters and setters for shortness
}


@Table(name = "hero")
@Entity(name = "hero")
public class Hero
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    //ommited getters and setters for shortness
}
```

As you see my Hero class doesn't have reference to heroic quality, and I would like to keep it that way.

Also I have a repository

```
@Repository
public interface HeroicQualityDAO
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<HeroicQuality, Long>
{
    Optional<HeroicQuality> findByName(String name);

    List<HeroicQuality> findByOrderByIdDesc();
}
```

What I would like to do is have a method such as

```
Optional<HeroicQuality> findByHeroName(String heroName)
```

Such that if given a name of hero from Hero table I will be able to get heroic quality object.

How can I make such a method?
Is there any way I can get heroic quality object without having a reference to it in the hero object?
How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following method to `HeroicQualityDAO`.

```
   Optional<HeroicQuality> findByHeroesName(String heroName);
```

If you are not happy with the method name, you can do

```
    @Query("Select h from HeroicQuality hq join hq.heros h where h.name = :name")
    Optional<HeroicQuality> findByHeroName(String name);
```